# React redux action resetting non attached state

Tags: reactjs, redux

When triggering an action `updateLog`, it seems it resets other state items. In my case updateLog should manipulate `log` and that works just fine. The thing is it also resets `tasks` to the default values. What am I doing wrong here?

Component:

```
class Generator extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="generator">
                <Inputs />
                <button onClick={this.generate.bind(this)}>Go!</button>                           
                <Log />                                
            </div>
        );
    }

    generate() {        
        this.props.updateLog("ANYTHING!");
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        tasks: state.tasks        
    };
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({updateLog: updateLog}, dispatch);
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Generator);
```

Action:

```
export const updateLog = (message) => {
    return {
        type: 'LOG_UPDATED',
        payload: message
    }
};
```

Logreducer:

```
const initialLog = "";

export default function (state = initialLog, action) {    
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOG_UPDATED':            
            return state + "\n" + action.payload            
            break;
    }    
    return state;
}
```

All reducers:

```
const allReducers = combineReducers({
    tasks: taskReducer,
    log: logReducer
});

export default allReducers
```

taskReducer:

```
export default function (state = null, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TASK_UPDATED':
            var tasks = Object.assign({}, action.payload);            
            return tasks;
            break;
    }

    // Default task properties
    return {
        CreateDatabaseTask: {
            enabled: false,
            type: "sqlite"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in your task reducer. **If the action type matches none of the ones defined in the switch statement, you should return the current state.** Instead, you are returning the initial state.

---

Try changing it to return the current state instead:

```
const initialState = {
    CreateDatabaseTask: {
        enabled: false,
        type: "sqlite"
    }
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TASK_UPDATED':
            var tasks = Object.assign({}, action.payload);            
            return tasks;
            break;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks @Timo. I understand the mistake about the initialState, but howcome the taskReducer is called in the first place? UpdateLog only manipulates state.log, therefore I thought the state-action-reducing chain was selective and only updated the minimum in this case log. Or the react/redux smartness is only in regards to render() ? Hope that makes sense, again thanks!

Comment: All your reducers are called every time you dispatch an action, which is why you need to return the current state if it shouldn't change